# plugin is not defined

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I try to use plugin [phonegap-googlemaps-plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin) in my cordova app. I follow the [manual-installation](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/Manual-Installation) steps. But code `var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap();` produce "plugin is not defined" error.

Where is my fault?

Comment: have you included the given js file in your index.html file?

Comment: Thank you. No, I haven't. But include googlemaps-cdv-plugin.js doesn't help - I still gte the error

Comment: Looks like that the problem that "module" isn't defined. The code failed in the following construction: `module.exports = {...}`. So, the code that defined window.plugin and other is never invoked.